Is there any chance that simplified forms of certain mathematical expressions throw overflow errors while complex ones dont?
I was attempting the #69 problem of leetcode, which involves finding square root of given number.
I proceeded via a binary search approach.
int mySqrt(int x) {
    if (x==0 || x==1){
        return x;
    }
    int start =1;
    int end=x;
    int mid=-1;
    while(start<=end){
        mid=(end+start)/2;//the problem lies here
        long long square=static_cast<long long>(mid)*mid;
        if (square>x){
            end=mid-1;
        }
        else if(square==x){
            return mid;
        }
        else{
            start=mid+1;
        }
     }
     return static_cast<int>(round(end));
}

When I changed mid=start+(end-start)/2;the test cases ran fine, however it threw 'signed integer overflow' for x=2147483647, saying 'runtime error: signed integer overflow: 2147483647 + 1 cannot be represented in type 'int''.

Did you pose this question on the LeetCode forums?  If not, why not?  If so, please link to that discussion here so we can read the responses.

Yes, 2147483647 + 1 overflows but 1 + (2147483647 - 1)/2 doesn't. (And the test case is constructed specifically to trigger this.) This was famously a bug in Java's SDK that went undected for years.

Partial response to question as asked, yes. For your particular case.... If start and end are both positive, and end > start then (1) end - start is representable as an int, and so is (end - start)/2 and (2) start + (end - start)/2 is between start and end, so also never overflows.  However, (end+start)/2 first computes end + start, which  (for large enough values e.g. start = INT_MAX - 10 and end = INT_MAX - 5) can overflow. Behaviour is then undefined - dividing by 2 does not magically fix consequences of overflow. You can do similar reasoning for other cases.

To answer the question directly: yes, different expressions that are mathematically equivalent can produce distinct results in a program.
In this case, if you first add start and end, then divide by 2, if their sum is larger than INT_MAX, you get integer overflow. However, if you subtract start from end, there cannot be overflow as you are subtracting two positive numbers.
However, even this approach is not completely correct if the numbers might be negative. Prefer using std::midpoint (since C++ 20) from the <numeric> header instead to avoid these issues altogether.
#include <numeric>
// ...
mid = std::midpoint(start, end);


@OP -- Replacing that line of code that is giving the issue with std::midpoint(start, end); solves the problem (is accepted by Leetcode).  I suggest you accept the answer given by Unmitigated.
